# CSS3 animation No effect

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

Using CSS3, HTML5, ASP.NET MVC4 C#. MS Visual Studio.

I have the following **CSS**...

```
.animated{-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
      -moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
      -ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
      animation-fill-mode:both;
      -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
      -moz-animation-duration:1s;
      -ms-animation-duration:1s;
      -o-animation-duration:1s;
      animation-duration:1s;}
@-webkit-keyframes bounceInRight {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2000px);
}   60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-30px);
}

80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
}

100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceInRight {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(2000px);
}

60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-30px);
}

80% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(10px);
}

100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
}
}

@keyframes bounceInRight {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(2000px);
}

60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(-30px);
}

80% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
}

100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
}

img.bounceInRight {
-webkit-animation-name: bounceInRight;
-moz-animation-name: bounceInRight;
animation-name: bounceInRight;
}
```

The **Razor View** snippet is...

```
<div class="row rowpadding">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            @Html.Action("BlogTags", "Blog")
            @Html.Action("BlogMonths", "Blog")  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            <div class="row rowpadding">
                @foreach (var item in Model.BlogPosts)
                {
                    if(isFirst)
                    {
                        isFirst = false;
                    } else
                    {
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 news-cata-div-size">
                        <div><img class="bounceInRight" src="~/Themes/Renray/Content/images/small-1.png" /></div>
                        <div><span class="News-item-Date">@item.CreatedOn.ToString("D")</span></div>
                        <div><a class="News-item-title" href="@Url.RouteUrl("BlogPost", new { SeName = item.SeName })">@item.Title</a></div>
                        <div class="post-body">
                           @Html.Raw((item.Body.Length > 200 ? item.Body.Substring(0,200) : item.Body))
                           <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("BlogPost", new { SeName = item.SeName })">
                               ...Read More?
                           </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    }
                }

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The reason why the view snippet i provided is large is because i want you guys to see the whole thing, as you may notice this is a **responsive build using bootstrap**.

As for the problem, the animation is supposed to **bounce from the right** every iteration of an image (view code is still incomplete for dynamic images, but that isn't relevant).

What happens on load is nothing, **no animation** effect at all. I'm wondering if you guys could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Many thanks!

Comment: Your `.animated` class isn't included in your Razor snippet. Is this class actually used?

Comment: good point, forgot to add it, what element should this be added too?

Comment: Your `img`, presumably.

Comment: yeh just did that works fine now, such a derp

Comment: post it as an answer and ill confirm it, cheers James!

Comment: I'll submit that as an answer instead of a comment then, I guess :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that your animation fill mode and duration are applied to an `.animated` class which isn't applied to any element within your Razor view.

To fix this, simply add this class to your `img` element:

```html
<img class="animated bounceInRight"
     src="~/Themes/Renray/Content/images/small-1.png" />
```

Alternatively, merge your `.animated` and `bounceInRight` classes:

```css
img.bounceInRight {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
    moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
    animation-fill-mode:both;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    -ms-animation-duration:1s;
    -o-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceInRight;
    -moz-animation-name: bounceInRight;
    animation-name: bounceInRight;
}
```